Line integral of a vector field over a triangle
I am trying to solve this line integral, but I get different answers when doing a normal line integral and using the vector form of green's theorem and am wondering why this is the case? I got 4 as my answer solving the line integral and 12 using green's theorem.
I am also confused as to why the integral has $d\mathbf{s}$, and not $d\mathbf{r}$, so any clarification on that would be awesome.
The question states:
Evaluate $\int_{C} \mathbf{F}\cdot d\mathbf{s}$ where $\mathbf{F} = \langle 2z,8x-3y,3x+y \rangle $ and $C$ is the triangle with vertices $(1,0,0), (0,1,0), (0,0,2)$
Attempt with line integrals:
Parametrizing $C$ into $C_1 = <1-t,t,0>$, $C_2 = <-,1-t,2t>$, and $C_3 = <5,0,2-2t>$ where $0\le t \le 1$
$$\int_{C} \mathbf{F}\cdot d\mathbf{s} = \sum_{i=1}^{3}\int_{C_i} \mathbf{F}\cdot d\mathbf{s} = \int_{C_1} \mathbf{F}\cdot d\mathbf{s} + \int_{C_2} \mathbf{F}\cdot d\mathbf{s} + \int_{C_3} \mathbf{F}\cdot d\mathbf{s}$$
$$\int_{C_1} \mathbf{F}\cdot d\mathbf{s} = \int_{0}^{1} \mathbf{F}(\mathbf{r}(t))\cdot \mathbf{r}\prime(t)dt$$
$$\int_{0}^{1} <2(0),8(1-t)-3(t),3(1-t)+(t)>\cdot<-1,1,0> dt$$
$$\int_{0}^{1} 8-8t-3t dt = \frac{5}{2}$$
With $C_2$ and $C_3$ being
$$\int_{C_2} \mathbf{F}\cdot d\mathbf{s} = \frac{5}{2}$$ and $$\int_{C_3} \mathbf{F}\cdot d\mathbf{s} = -1$$
So
$$\int_{C} \mathbf{F}\cdot d\mathbf{s} = \frac{5}{2} + \frac{5}{2} - 1 = 4$$
With Green's Theorem:
$$\int_{C} \mathbf{F}\cdot d\mathbf{s} = \iint_{D}curl\mathbf{F}\cdot k dA$$
$$curl\mathbf{F} = <1,-1,8>$$
$$\iint_{D}curl\mathbf{F}\cdot k dA = \iint_{D}8 dA$$
$$= 8 \iint_{D}dA$$ where $\iint_{D}dA$ would be the area of the triangle
area of triangle
$$A = \frac{1}{2}|<-1,1,0>\times<-1,0,2>| = \frac{\sqrt{9}}{2} = \frac{3}{2}$$
and so
$$8 \iint_{D}dA = 8 * \frac{3}{2} = 12$$
Any help on how to solve this would be greatly appreciated, thanks!

Show your work, please

It is a surface integral.

Sorry, added my work for both ways I tried.

The $\text{s}$ in $d\text{s}$ stands for surface. It's a surface integral as stated by @Sebastiano .
But if you wanted to compute the line integral over the triangle's border (with $d\text{r}$), your top attempt is correct.
For the bottom one, you need to normalize the normal vector before calculating the dot product with the curl. The normal vector $<-1,1,0> \times <-1,0,2>$ is equal to $<2,2,1>$ which has a norm of $\sqrt{9} = 3$.
That is why your bottom result is three times your top result.
